# WSO2 ESB - How process messages one by one (in series) from messages store

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I try use sample process and scheduler process to do it. But they are work by fixed intervals and don't wait finish previous message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forwarding message processor (class ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor) wait for the http response before dequeueing next message in the store, if the response is OK.

In case of error, 404 for exemple, it rollback JMS transaction and continue with the same message again and again.

The interval used in the ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor's definition is the interval use by the MP to dequeue next message after a response.